# Serverless Framework not creating AWS Scheduler trigger

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

For some reason, when I deploy my lambda it doesn't create a trigger. This is the extract from the yaml

```
org: simoncook
app: xxx
service: xxx

frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8

  iam:
    role: 'arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/MyLambdaRole'

functions:
  my_function:
    handler: handler.my_function
    events:
      - schedule:
          method: scheduler
          rate:
            - cron(0 6 * * ? *)
          timezone: Europe/London
    timeout: 60
```

This is adapted straight from the [serverless documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule#use-awsschedulerschedule-instead-of-awseventrule), so not sure why it isn't working. It's not showing any errors at all - just doing nothing!

Comment: Is that a full `serverless.yml` configuration? What is the output of the deploy command? Does it deploy the function and just misses the event or the function isn't deployed as well?

Comment: Hi - it's not the complete serverless.yml - I've amended the original post to show all the declarations. 

It deploys fine - just the scheduler configuration isn't picked up by AWS

Comment: Did you check CloudFormation events/logs for error? Though schedule events are by default enabled but still just to check can you add `enabled: true` in your yaml

Comment: https://forum.serverless.com/t/possible-bug-with-scheduled-event-definitions/8153/2